# Does identity theorem for meromorphic function on the complex manifold holds true?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

I know that identity theorem for the meromorphic function on the complex plane holds ture. The proof goes as follows:

Assume the meromorphic function $f = a/b,g= m/n$ where $a,b,m,n$ are holomorphic function if$f = g$ on an open subset $U$ then $an - bm$ as holomorphic function is zero on this open subset therefore it's constant zero, i.e. $f = g$ everywhere

Does the identity theorem for the complex manifold holds ture?To be more precise:

Let $X$ be a connected complex manifold, and $f, g$ be two meromorphic functions on $X$, assume there is an open set $U$ such that $f|_U = g|_U$ is it true that $f = g$ on $X$ .

Comment: It will be very helpful if the detialed proof is provided

Comment: What did you try? Where are you stuck?

Hint - consider the set where f=g. Show that it is both open and closed.

Comment: @Espace' etale  , I have used some idea similar to analytic continuation to prove the result, can you provide more detail on how to use open closed argument to prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's sufficient to prove if $f$ as a meromorphic function is zero on an open subset $U$ then it's constant zero globally.

Let $p\in V\subset U$ such that on $V$,meromorphic function $f$ is represented as $f= a/b$ therefore $a$ is constant zero on $V$.

Let $q\in X$ be another point, there is a path connecting $p,q$ at each point of the path exists an open neighborhood (if shirnk furthure we may assume it's connected) that meromorphic function has local representation as quotient of holomorphic functions locally on that neighborhood. And we can find finite number of such open sets $V= U_0, U_1,....,U_n$ covering the path.

**I claim on each $U_i$ the meromorphic function $f$ is identically zero on $U_i$ by induction**

At the intersection $U_i\cap U_{i+1}$ of two such open sets, we have compatible condition $a_i/b_i = a_{i+1}/b_{i+1}$ and $a_i =0$ is identically zero by induction hypothsis, therefore, $a_{i+1}b_i = 0$ on $U_{i+1}\cap U_i$ since $b_i$ is not identical zero, we have $a_{i+1} = 0$ on $U_i \cap U_{i+1}$ hence also $U_{i+1}$, therefore all the representative along the path is identical zero meromorphic functions.

Therefore $f$ is a globally zero meromorphic function.

Comment: it's unfair to downvote my post!

Comment: While I did not vote your post down, I can see why someone would. 
1. You are asking for assistance in an undergraduate level question, without saying what is your main problem or main ideas. It is unpedagogical to answer you without this background.
2. You should look at this post: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question
3. Not as important, but also notice that a meromorphic function is (at least a-priori) not exactly the same as the quotient of two holomorphic functions...

Comment: @Espace' etale  thank you for pointing out the problem, meromorphic function on the complex manifold is locally defined to be the quotient of two holomorphic function ? It should not be undergrad problem.